# xpages retrieve value from Date list

Tags: xpages

Question:

1. I store my Date value in list using code below.

   ```
   if (document1.hasItem("NotifyDate")){
       var nd = document1.getItemValue("NotifyDate");
       nd.addElement(session.createDateTime(@Now()));
       document1.setValue("NotifyDate", nd);
   }else{
       document1.setValue("NotifyDate", session.createDateTime(@Now()));
   }
   ```
2. I want to retrieve it to display in webpage everytime i append an
   item.

   ```
   I18n.toString(document1.getItemValue("NotifyDate").lastElement().toJavaDate(), "dd/MM/yyyy") +")"
   ```

Problem :

1. List item i only can get last element. How can i get all element of one field to display it

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use loop to create output string.

```
var result="Status notification ( ";
for(var i=0; i<document1.getItemValue("NotifyDate").length;i++){
    result+= I18n.toString(document1.getItemValue("NotifyDate").get(i).toJavaDate(), "dd/MM/yyyy") +" "
}
result+=")"
return result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . This solve the problem.  I got think of loop but i don "get" is the "key" word for it. i use wrong method,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a repeat to list each value from the date field. Here's an example:

```
<xp:repeat value="#{document1.NotifyDate}" var="singleDate" removeRepeat="true">
    I18n.toString(singleDate.toJavaDate(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: Actually i need to display it inside a "label". to display multiple date! In order to do that, do i need to create another repeat control inside it?